# Installing TFS 2008 Workgroup Edition on Windows Server 2003 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, windows, tfs

I ran into an issue when installing Team Foundation Server 2008 Workgroup Edition. I have a Windows Server 2003 SP2 machine that's practically new. I have installed SQL Server 2008 with almost all of the options. When I run through the TFS installation, it allows me to enter my SQL instance name and then goes through the verification process to ensure I have everything I need. However, I receive an error stating that

> A compatible version of SQL Server is not installed.

I verified and I do have SQL Server 2008 running just fine. It's Standard edition and does have Full Text, Reporting, and Analysis services installed. The other errors I receive are with Full Text not being installed, running, or enabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Team Foundation Server 2008 against SQL Server 2008, you must use TFS 2008 Service Pack 1.  However, currently Microsoft do not provide a "TFS with SP1" download - you must created your own slipstreamed installation by downloading the TFS 2008 media and then applying the service pack to the media before running the installer.

For more information see my blog post here

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/creating_a_tfs.html

Also note that TFS needs certain settings for its SQL Server. When installing a SQL instance for TFS I usually follow the guidance in the TFS Installation Guide pretty ridgedly just to be sure I have everything set up right.  You can download the latest copy of the TFS install guide here

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FF12844F-398C-4FE9-8B0D-9E84181D9923&displaylang=en

Good luck,

Martin.

Comment: I just checked out your procedure and tried to follow it, but it doesn't appear like all the files are in the sp1 package. I don't see the .exe you mentioned. There is a .msp installer package and a .exe hotfix. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Tfs 2008 Sp1 for support for SQL Server 2008. See this post [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126150345/http://geekswithblogs.net/etiennetremblay/archive/2008/08/11/sql-2008--tfs-2008-sp1-the-lowdownhellip.aspx)

Hth.,
/Gert

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that won't work since I don't have TFS installed at all yet. If I could get it installed, I would be able to do the SP1.

Answer (score 1):

Martin - Thanks for the post. I found a cleaner version of your procedure and blogged about it at http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2008/09/24/installing-team-foundation-server-2008-on-sql-server-2008.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an article in the TFS Installation Guide
called "How to: Integrate the Installation of Team Foundation Server and Service Pack 1 "

Extract TFS DVD to 'TFS2008'
Extract TFS SP1 to 'SP1'
Run this command from the directory they're both in
Run installer from TFS2008WITHSP1

Note: target dir seems to need to be fully qualified

MSIEXEC /a TFS2008\AT\VS_SETUP.MSI /p SP1\TFS90sp1-KB949786.msp TARGETDIR=s:\software\msdn\servers\TFS2008WITHSP1